# How to get array of objects with no duplicate values by adding 1 using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, object

I have arrayof object  `arrlist` and parameter `uid`

If property `value` has duplicate value(ignore null) and `id` not same as `uid`, then
autoincrement the value until no duplicate value.

How to do the above scenario using javascript. tried but got stuck.

```
var uid1 = 26
var arrlist1 = [
  {id: 11 , value: 2},
  {id: 14, value: null},
  {id: 28, value: 1},
  {id: 26, value: 3},
  {id: 78, value: 3}
]

Expected Output

[
  {id: 11 , value: 2},
  {id: 14, value: null},
  {id: 28, value: 1},
  {id: 26, value: 3},
  {id: 78, value: 4}
]

In the above scenario, 
{id: 26, value: 3} is not incremented since id matches with uid

for `id` 78, `value` 3 is duplicate, so increment it
 {id: 78, value: 4}
and no more duplicate return expected output.
```

```
var uid2 = 78
var arrlist2 = [
  {id: 11 , value: 2},
  {id: 14, value: null},
  {id: 28, value: 1},
  {id: 26, value: 3},
  {id: 78, value: 1}
]

Expected Output

[
  {id: 11 , value: 3},
  {id: 14, value: null},
  {id: 28, value: 2},
  {id: 26, value: 4},
  {id: 78, value: 1}
]

In the above scenario, 
{id: 78, value: 1} is not incremented since id matches with uid

for `id` 28, `value` 1 is duplicate, so increment it becomes
{id: 28, value: 2}
for `id` 11 `value` 2 is duplicate, so increment it becomes
{id: 11, value: 3}
for `id` 26 `value` 3 is duplicate, so increment it becomes
{id: 26, value: 4}

and no more duplicate return expected output.
```

```
Tried
const result = this.getArrObj(arrlist1, uid1)

function getArrObj (arrlist, uid) {
  const totalobj = arrlist.filter(e=>e!==null).length);

  var finalArrObj = arrlist.map(itm => ({
    ...itm,
    value: (itm.value && (itm.id !== uid && itm.value <= totalobj)) ?  
      (itm.value || 0) + 1 : itm.value
  })

}
```

Comment: The expected output is identical to the input?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, thanks for reply, meaning `value` if got duplicate will differ

Comment: is it crucial that in the second example id `11` has value of `3` and id `28` has value of `2` and not reverse?

Comment: @wonderflame, thanks for reply, id `28` has duplicate value `1` so increment it, becomes 2 then id `11` which got incremented has duplicate `2` then increment it becomes 3

Comment: what I mean is it okay that `11` would become `2` and `28` become `3`?

Comment: @wonderflame no for the second example

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, are those 2 examples, or are they part of the same question? Please add some more details like how you get the desired output

Comment: @0stone0 thanks for reply, have update the question, added description for each example

Comment: @Codelearn In the first example `26` and `78` has same value but you want to increment only the next duplicate which is not same as `uid` ?

Comment: @DecPK yes correct,  want to increment only the next duplicate which is not same as uid

Comment: and then if we increment next value so it will incement by 1 and then we have to again check if it  matches with another value in that array or not. Right?

Comment: @DecPK yes correct, until no duplicates increment it

Comment: @DecPK any solution how to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function incrementDuplicate(arrlist2, id) {
  // Helper function to check for duplicates
  function hasDuplicates(array) {
    return new Set(array).size !== array.length;
  }

  // Get the values from the array
  const values = arrlist2.map(obj => obj.value);

  // Check for duplicate values (other than the passed id)
  if (hasDuplicates(values) && id !== null) {
    const duplicateValue = values.find(value => value !== null && values.indexOf(value) !== values.lastIndexOf(value));

    if (duplicateValue !== undefined) {
      // Find the object with the duplicate value
      const duplicateObject = arrlist2.find(obj => obj.value === duplicateValue && obj.id !== id);

      // Increment the value of the duplicate object
      duplicateObject.value++;

      // Keep track of modified id
      const modifiedId = duplicateObject.id;

      // Recursively check for additional duplicates
      incrementDuplicate(arrlist2, modifiedId);
    }
  }

  return arrlist2;
}
```

Solution 2

```
function incrementDuplicate(arrlist2, id) {
  const valueToIdMap = new Map();
  for (const obj of arrlist2) {
     if (obj.id !== id) {
      valueToIdMap.set(obj.value, obj.id);
     }
  }
  const matchingObj = arrlist2.find(o => o.id === id);
  const valueToSearch = matchingObj.value;
  for (const [k,v] of valueToIdMap) {
      if (k >= valueToSearch) {
          const indexToModify = arrlist2.findIndex(o => o.id === v);
          arrlist2.splice(indexToModify, 1, { id: v, value: k + 1});
      }
  }
  return arrlist2;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, have update the question, added description for each example. but code works diffrently

Comment: Updated the code above.

Comment: thanks for reply, it failes for second example

Comment: updated the function again, please take a look

Comment: thanks for reply, is there any way to do single map function since am using sequelize