# How to auto increment the property having same value in object array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have array of object, how to autoincrement until property `value` is not same using map

or for... of using javascript

scenario 1

```js
var arrobj = [
  { value: 2},
  { value: 1},
  { value: 1},
  { value: 4},
]
```

Expected Output

```js
[
  { value: 3},
  { value: 1},
  { value: 2},
  { value: 4},
]
```

Tried

```js
for (var itm of arrobj) {
  for (var itm1 of arrobj) {
     if(itm.value === itm1.value) {
       value: itm.value + 1
     } 
     value: itm.value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achive your end result using `.map`, include an index to check on the previous item of `arrobj`.

- If previous exists compare value and increment if same.
- first item in array has nothing to compare so it automatically gets incremented.

```js
var arrobj = [
  { value: 2},
  { value: 1},
  { value: 1},
  { value: 4},
]

const newArr = arrobj.map((currObj, index) => {
  // nothing to compare then always increment
  firstObjInArr = index == 0; 
  
  // look at previous item to compare value
  prevObj = arrobj[index-1];   
  prevAndCurrValuesMatch = prevObj?.value === currObj.value

  if (prevAndCurrValuesMatch || firstObjInArr) {
    currObj.value += 1;  
  }
  
  return currObj;
});


console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, what if i pass one more parameter id, how to set index https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76466040/how-to-get-array-of-objects-with-no-duplicate-values-by-adding-1-using-javascrip/76466097?noredirect=1#comment134831386_76466097